# $|φ^{(m+1)}(x) - \frac{φ^{(m)}(x)-φ^{(m)}(x-\alpha)}{\alpha} | = |\int_{0}^{1}φ^{(m+1)}(x)ds - \int_{0}^{1}φ^{(m+1)}(x+\alpha(s-1))ds|$

Tags: analysis

Why is

$$
\begin{split}
\psi_\alpha ^{(m)} (x)
 &= |φ^{(m+1)}(x) - \frac{\phi^{(m)}(x)-\phi^{(m)}(x-\alpha)}{\alpha} | \\
 &= \left|\int_{0}^{1}\phi^{(m+1)}(x)ds
        - \int_{0}^{1}\phi^{(m+1)}(x+\alpha(s-1))ds\right|
\end{split}
$$

I cant see where the integral comes from

$ φ ∈ C_0^∞(ℝ)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any differentiable function $f$
$$
\int_0^1f'(x+\alpha(s-1))\,ds=\int_{x-\alpha}^xf'(t)\,\frac{dt}{\alpha}=\frac{f(x)-f(x-\alpha)}{\alpha}.
$$
Apply this to $f=\phi^{(m)}$.

For the first integral, observe that the variable of integration is $s$, and that the integrand is constant.

Comment: Cheers mate, I appreciate the help